# Python 3: Binary search tree, size-function not returning number of nodes

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I'm implementing a (recursive) binary search tree and I can't get the `size` function working. This is my code so far:

```
class BinarySearchTreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

    def add(self, data):
        if self.data == data:
            return False
        elif data < self.data:
            if self.left:
                return self.left.add(data)
            else:
                self.left = BinarySearchTreeNode(data)
                return True
        else:
            if self.right:
                return self.right.add(data)
            else:
                self.right = BinarySearchTreeNode(data)
                return True

    def contains(self, data):
        if self.data == data:
            return True
        elif self.data > data:
            if self.left:
                return self.left.contains(data)
            else:
                return False
        else:
            if self.right:
                return self.right.contains(data)
            else:
                return False

    def size(self):
        if self.left and self.right:
            return 1 + self.left.size() + self.right.size()
        elif self.left:
            return 1 + self.left.size()
        elif self.right:
            return 1 + self.right.size()
        else:
            return 1


class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def add(self, data): 
        if not self.root:
            self.root = BinarySearchTreeNode(data)
            return True
        else:
            return self.root.add(data)

    def contains(self, data):
        if self.root:
            return self.root.contains(data)
        else:
            return False

    def clear(self):
        self.root = None

    def size(self):
        if self.root is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return self.root.size()


bst = BinarySearchTree()

bst.add(3)
bst.add(24)
bst.add(7)
bst.add(15)
bst.add(2)
bst.add(19)

bst.size()
```

I want the `size` function to be called from the `BinarySearchTree` class but executed via the `BinarySearchTreeNode` class. I have tried everything I can think of, but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there *any* input data with which this works?  When it doesn't work, *how* does the result differ from what was expected?  At what point in your debugging did things start to stray from what was expected?

Comment: Shouldn't `BinarySearchTreeNode` have an `__init__` method?

Comment: I do have an __init__ method for the class BinarySearchTreeNode. Somehow I forgot to include it when I copied the code here

Comment: The input data works with the add-function and the contains-function. If i add a print-statement after the first if-statement and the two elif-statements, it does print out every element. Without the print-statements the program executes without any error, but no value is returned. I want the size-function to return the actual number of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is this?

```
class BinarySearchTreeNode:

    self.data = data
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
```

This is not an initializing process you're doing there mate. Try the following:

```
class BinarySearchTreeNode:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

Even checked it for you:

```
In[1]: 
bst = BinarySearchTree()
bst.add(3)
bst.add(24)
bst.add(7)
bst.add(15)
bst.add(2)
bst.add(19)
bst.size()
Out[2]: 6
```

Comment: I do have an __init__ method for the class BinarySearchTreeNode. Somehow I forgot to include it when I copied the code here

Comment: First, Re-edit your question with the correction. Second, it works for me. It should work for you as well. After you correct your code I will have a 2nd look.

Comment: I have re-edited my question. I think it does work for me, it's just that I don't get any output. The program executes without any errors. Thank you!

Comment: try print(bst.size()) :}}}}}

Comment: Oh, it was that easy, thank you so much! Why is not enough, though to use return statements? If I'm not completely mistaken, in Java it would be enough to use the return statement

Comment: Nah. Return statement just returns the value to where ever you want to store it. Why would it print it on the screen if you didn't tell it to? You can just make a variable `tree_size = bst.size()` and then `print(tree_size)`.

Comment: Np. Please do not forget to mark the question as answered.